# Javascript "deep" check for defined

Tags: javascript, typescript

I could swear that once upon a time, I came across some code that used some js library (maybe lodash??) to do a "deep" check for whether something is defined.

Example:

```
someLib.isDefined(anObject.aNestedObject.anotherNestedObject);
```

(would return true if anotherNestedObject is defined, but would return false (and not throw an exception) if anObject or aNestedObject were undefined.

Did I totally dream that, or is there some well-known function out there that does that?

Comment: I don't think that it's possible. The expression `anObject.aNestedObject.anotherNestedObject` is evaluated before the `someLib.isDefined` function is invoked so an exception will be thrown (if `anObject` or `aNestedObject` don't exist) before the function had a chance to do anything. Maybe if you'd pass it as a string: `someLib.isDefined("anObject.aNestedObject.anotherNestedObject")`

Comment: only if that argument was a string

Comment: can use a `try/catch`

Comment: There is... lodash's has() function. He didn't ask specifically for a vanilla JS solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lodash's has():

```
_.has(object, path)
```

Example:

```
var object = {a: {b: 'test', c: 'test2'}};
_.has(object, 'a.b');
// => true
_.has(object, 'a.d');
// => false
```

[Full documentation](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4#has)
[Source code for _.has()](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.16.4/lodash.js#L6045)

Comment: Sorry didn't notice you meant checking existence, edited.

Comment: That's the one -- I knew I had seen that somewhere!  Thank you sir.

Answer (score 2):

As I wrote in my comment I don't think that it's possible.
The expression `anObject.aNestedObject.anotherNestedObject` is evaluated before the `someLib.isDefined` function is invoked so an exception will be thrown (if anObject or aNestedObject don't exist) before the function had a chance to do anything.
Maybe if you'd pass it as a string: someLib.isDefined("anObject.aNestedObject.anotherNestedObjec‌​t")

But, it's easy to check that like this:

```
if (anObject && anObject.aNestedObject && anObject.aNestedObject.anotherNestedObject) {
    ...
}
```

Or just implement your own function, it's pretty simple:

```
function exists(obj: any, keys: string | string[]) {
    if (typeof keys === "string") {
        keys = keys.split(".");
    }

    return keys.every(key => {
        if (!obj) {
            return false;
        }

        obj = obj[key];
        return true;
    });
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20exists(obj%3A%20any%2C%20keys%3A%20string%20%7C%20string%5B%5D)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(typeof%20keys%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22string%22)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20keys%20%3D%20keys.split(%22.%22)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20keys.every(key%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(!obj)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20false%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20obj%20%3D%20obj%5Bkey%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20true%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%7D))

Answer (score 1):

No there is no well-known function to do this, but you can check it safely in this way:

```
if (typeof anObject != "undefined"  
&& typeof anObject.aNestedObject != "undefined" 
&& typeof anObject.aNestedObject.anotherNestedObject != "undefined") {
   console.log("defined");
}else{
  console.log("undefined");
}
```